# RichFaces Toolbargroup centering a group

Tags: jsf, jboss, richfaces

I am trying use a toolbar so that it has three parts

part A is aligned left

part B is aligned Center

part C is aligned right

both the right and left i can use the location attribute ... but since there is no center attribute i am not able to center part b.

I can use a rich:spacer but this makes the toolbar rigid and when the screen size is reduced the toolbar gets overlapped ... is there any i can center this without the toolbar getting over lapped.

Any suggestions or workarounds is welcome

cheers